# tcpdump slowed down by... its own filter?

Tags: tcp, udp, ip, packet-capture, tcpdump

Do long BPF filters slow down `tcpdump`?

I replay a packet trace where all the packets have `ttl=k` and wait for **ICMP** messages back. What I've been noticing is that if I use the following filter (on eth0):

```
(ip and ip[8]=$k and src host $myAddress) or (icmp and dst host $myAddress and icmp[0]=11)
```

...I always miss 20-30 packets among the sent packets, whereas if I just do:

```
ip
```

... and then do the exact above filtering **offline** on the capture file, I find all the packets I had sent.

Is this a known behaviour?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If `tcpdump` is not fast enough to pop out captured packets from the queue, the kernel could drop some of them.

Look at the **"XXXX packets dropped by kernel"** message at the end of the dump to see if effectively some of them is lost.

Ensure to add the `-n` option to the command line. This will avoid DNS resolving and it will speed up a little (depending on your network)